# How to export grid data to excel along group headers/ summary records with expand and collapse action in Excel?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have done application using Extjs 4. I have requirement need to export grid data to excel. I have grid it contains many records, showing records by group headers/summary(collapse/Expand actions ). **The same thing i need to export grid data to excel the same activity need collapse/expand in excel sheet**. I have tried i am able to export grid records with group headers.summary to excel, cool it is working but collapse/expand is not happening in excel sheet. I need to implement this feature by writing a code. **Can anybody tell me how to achieve this one? is it possible or not by using extjs?** great appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this doesn't come out of the box. There is however some exporter from ExtJS to Excel: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?136598-Export-store-to-Excel

We we internally do is generate our Excel backend with .NET so we have more control.